# detecting keys by variables Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to make the keys that are to be detected customizable by the user.
Using a variable after the dot from keys doesn't work though. It says it is not a member. What could i try?

```
    If keysformovment = "customized" Then
         If e.KeyCode = Keys.moveToRight Then
             MoveRight = False
         End If
         If e.KeyCode = Keys.moveToLeft Then
             MoveLeft = False
         End If
    End If
```

Comment: I don't think you are showing us enough code. What is `Keys`, and how are the customized keys stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Keys` is an enumeration.  It's part of the .NET framework.  It's declared in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.  Here is the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) for the enumeration.  If you are curious, [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Keys.cs) is the source code for it (in C#).

Just like any other enumeration, the name after the dot has to be one of the valid names that is declared in the enumeration.  However, since all of the values in the enumeration are `Integer`, you can just compare the value of `KeyCode` to an integer.  For instance, since `Keys.Left = 37`, the following two things are equivalent:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Left Then
    ' ...
End If
```

Is the same as:

```
Dim moveToLeft As Integer = 37
If e.KeyCode = moveToLeft Then
    ' ...
End If
```

However, it would be better to keep the value typed as an enumeration as far as possible, and only deal with the value as an `Integer` as low as possible.  In other words, type it typed appropriately throughout as much of your code as you can and convert it from an integer to the enumeration as soon as you can.  For instance:

```
Public Function LoadKeySetting() As Keys
    Dim value As Integer = ' Load from file
    Return CType(value, Keys)
End Function

' ...

Dim moveToLeft As Keys = LoadKeySetting()
If e.KeyCode = moveToLeft Then
    ' ...
End If
```